# DependsOn debugging

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, gradle-plugin

I am developing gradle plugin with unit testing
I am developing task that depends on other task from other plugin
i am using org.gradle.testfixtures.ProjectBuilder for emulate test project.

```
Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().withProjectDir(FIXTURE_WORKING_DIR).build()
    project.apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    project.apply plugin: 'com.tac.kulik.uploadapk'
    project.android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 22
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            alpha{

            }
        }
    }
```

then i use depending tasks

```
    def myTaskName = "myTask${variationName}"
    def outputData = variant.outputs.first()
    def assembleTask = outputData.assemble
    def myTask = project.tasks.create(myTaskName, MyTask)

    myTaskTask.dependsOn assembleTask
```

Then I call my Task from test

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Project project = TestHelper.evaluatableProject()
    project.evaluate()

    project.tasks.myTaskFreeRelease.execute()
}
```

My Task was called. But assemble task wasn't (output files from this task not found). How to correctly call task sequence from test script?

**UPDATE**
It work's on real project. Task sequence was called, but it doesn't work from tests
Real problem that test project build dir doesn't exist at all. Please help me with this. It look like test Project build directory doesn't created at all. Look like it is just evalating, but doesn't use any file operations.

Comment: Your task does not depend on `assemble` task.

Comment: Sorry if you mean publishApkTask - it is just question publication mistake
i used myTask.dependsOn assembleTask. Assemble Task - it is android assemble task. So i am accepted that APK file will be available. but just file path available (it is not null, and look like real path.) so file not found exception appeared